# Creating a proFTPd user

Tags: users, configuration, symlink, ftp, proftpd

I'm setting up a proFTPd server so I can upload files to my webserver, but I've never tried this before. I've installed `proftpd`, added a user with a home folder: `/home/FTP-shared` and added `/bin/false` shell to it as well.

But what do I do configuration-wise now in `proftp` to be able to login with this user, and up and download, delete and so on?

And my idea was to symlink to Apache `www` folder from the ftp user directory? Will that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can read it [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html).

For your second question, I'm currently using `mount --bind`.

Comment: Okay i made this, but dont seem to work?
http://pastebin.com/8ddnJX7N

Comment: i found my problem, it was actually my useralias that was wrong.

My limits works :) thanks!